# create-react-app command stuck on installing react react-dom react-scripts with cra-template

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, installation

I have installed node.js today and initiated the npm install -g create-react-app command successfully. But after that when I use npm create-react-app appname command, it's just stuck in the step-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ch0VK.png)

and it's almost 2 hours with no response. I have tried other commands like npm init too which are working perfectly but this is taking so long with no response. I'm working on a 32 bit windows computer with npm version 6.14.5 and node version 12.18.2. Also, the network is working fine so I'm sure that's not the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue, I have done 3 things,

1. Just reset the firewall & security settings as default.
2. Re-install your node-js & restart your PC.

Now it is working fine.

Images from Npm:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just install a 32 bit version of node on windows and try again.
This solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Use **npx create-react-app my-app** instead to create an react App.
See official docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Comment: Tried doing that too, but the results are same.

Answer (score 0):

Just reset the firewall & security settings as default.
Re-install your node-js & restart your PC.
Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

**I had the same issue.**

I tried to reset the firewall & security settings as default. `Re-install node-js` & `restart` my PC.

Then I tried this `npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template` using this official [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/custom-templates)

It worked!